# How to deploy tizen tv apps to many internal tv

Tags: deployment, automation, tizen

I have develop internal Tizen TV apps for showing reporting from internal server to 200 Tizen TV. After I finished my development, I want to deploy to 200 Tizen TV.

I know that Tizen TV have development mode that point to my PC. I'm happy in development testing because I can connect my Tizen Studio to my Tizen TV.

This is my solution for deploy to 200 Tizen TV:

1. I configure 200 Tizen TV to development mode and point to my Tizen Studio, then I can inject my apps. This solution take much time for me.
2. I will publish this apps to Tizen Store, that I know it's imposible because there is an internal testing from Tizen Team and I cann't show data from my internal server to their testing Tizen TV
3. I copy my apps to flashdisk, but this fiture was disabled for security reason

Is there somebody here tell me best practice how to deploy 200 Tizen TV in my case?

Answer (score 0):

**Just an idea.** It seems to be doable with **`sdb`** by

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=2; c<=201; c++ ))
do  
   sdb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.$c
   sdb install <path to package>/package name.tpk
   sdb disconnect xxx.xxx.xxx.$c
done
```

Supposing Your PC is xxx.xxx.xxx.1 and TVs are from 2 to 201

For full spec of **`sdb`** visit https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.devtools/html/common_tools/smart_dev_bridge.htm

**`sdb`** is located in `tizen-studio/tools/`